# json remapping with jq

Tags: json, bash, ubuntu, jq

I have the following json:

```
[
  {
    "ip": [
      "8.8.4.4/32",
      "212.40.11.20/32"
    ],
    "port": 25,
    "proto": "tcp"
  },
  {
    "ip": [
      "212.40.11.30/32"
    ],
    "port": 3389,
    "proto": "tcp"
  }
]
```

Using `jq` I want to separate the ip addresses in the `ip` array, like this:

```
[
  {
    "ip": "8.8.4.4/32",
    "port": 25,
    "proto": "tcp"
  },
  {
    "ip": "212.40.11.20/32",
    "port": 25,
    "proto": "tcp"
  },
  {
    "ip": "212.40.11.30/32",
    "port": 3389,
    "proto": "tcp"
  }
]
```

I'm using `jq 1.5` on `Ubuntu 15.04` with `bash 4.3.42(1)`.

EDIT:
This is how I generated this list from AWS:
`aws ec2 describe-security-groups --group-id sg-2cf5e31 --query 'SecurityGroups[].IpPermissions[].{port:ToPort,proto:IpProtocol,ip:IpRanges[].CidrIp[]}' | jq '.[]'`

Next step would be adding a custom field.

Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A shorter and simpler alternative than both @peak's and @hek2mgl's, but still fundamentally operating on the same concept:

```
jq 'map(.ip = .ip[])'
```

Comment: Wow! Clean and simple!

Comment: Works like a charm and incredibly elegant, thank you!

Comment: BTW Can you think of a way to do it with the `aws` tool leaving out `jq`?

Comment: Not at the moment, but someone probably can! I would create a separate question for that. The `--query` parameter inside AWS takes JMESPath commands, which are really similar to jq commands.

Answer (score 4):

```
$ jq 'map(  (.ip[] | { "ip": .}) + del(.ip) )' input.json
[
  {
    "ip": "8.8.4.4/32",
    "port": 25,
    "proto": "tcp"
  },
  {
    "ip": "212.40.11.20/32",
    "port": 25,
    "proto": "tcp"
  },
  {
    "ip": "212.40.11.30/32",
    "port": 3389,
    "proto": "tcp"
  }
]
```

Equivalently, one can write `map( . + {ip:.ip[]} )`.

That is (and this is one of those things that make jq so powerful), if STREAMn is a stream of length n, then `value + STREAMn` yields a stream of length n, assuming (value + x) is valid for each item in the stream.

Indeed, `STREAMn + STREAMm` yields the "Cartesian product stream" of length m * n, assuming the items can be added pairwise.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to [Peak's nice solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34119160/171318), you can use the following expression:

```
jq '[.[]|{ip:.ip[],port,proto}]' aws.json
```

It shows nicely how `jq` "flattens" the *ip* array.

Output:

```
[
  {
    "ip": "8.8.4.4/32",
    "port": 25,
    "proto": "tcp"
  },
  {
    "ip": "212.40.11.20/32",
    "port": 25,
    "proto": "tcp"
  },
  {
    "ip": "212.40.11.30/32",
    "port": 3389,
    "proto": "tcp"
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you, quite awesome as well!